# How to draw multiple 2d circles on top of buffer geometry?

Tags: three.js, 2d, texture-mapping, buffer-geometry

Want to add multiple circles (with radius and coords) on top layer of a buffer geometry and mesh lambert material.

Desired result needs to come like this below image. It is already a buffer geometry with polygons and colors on top it want to draw that two circles white and brown with different radius and different coords. How to achieve it?

[Sample Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHHrv.png)